# How to convert "month-day" object to date format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I have a df with a column:

| column |
| --- |
| Dec-01 |

The column datatype is an object.

I am trying to change it to a datatype date.

This is what I've tried:

```
df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column']).dt.strftime(%d-%b')
```

This is the error I receive:

> pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-12-01 00:00:00

Would really appreciate you help

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want `pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format='%b-%d')`?

Comment: I would like it to be 12/01/22 format. My initial thoughts were to convert the datatype from object to date firsthand then move onto formatting. @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format='%b-%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d/22')
```

*NB. you must hardcode the year as it is undefined in your original data and pandas will by default use 1970.*

output:

```
   column      date
0  Dec-01  12/01/22
```